# push rejected Heroku Python Flask requirements failing exiv2==0.3.1

Tags: python, git, flask, heroku, exiv2

I am attempting to push my flask app to heroku for hosting.  All was going well until the PUSH to heroku.  I am receiving an error during `remote:Building source:` and the requirement for exiv2==0.3.1 cannot be satisfied. [exiv2==0.3.1](https://pypi.org/project/exiv2/) I understand that the requirements section is usually where errors occur, based on the reading I've been doing.  However, I am unsure how to proceed besides removing the exiv2 reliant code and losing some functionality...???

requirements.txt

```
altgraph==0.17
asgiref==3.2.10
blinker==1.4
blurhash==1.1.4
boost==0.1
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
cmake==3.17.3
cycler==0.10.0
decorator==4.4.2
dlib==19.20.0
dnspython==2.0.0
docutils==0.16
email-validator==1.1.1
exiv2==0.3.1  <-------------------(ITS here format/version is correct)
face-recognition==1.3.0
face-recognition-models==0.3.0
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.8
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-WTF==0.14.3
future==0.18.2
idna==2.10
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
joblib==0.16.0
Kivy==1.11.1
kivy-deps.angle==0.2.0
kivy-deps.glew==0.2.0
kivy-deps.sdl2==0.2.0
Kivy-Garden==0.1.4
kiwisolver==1.2.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
Mastodon.py==1.5.1
matplotlib==3.3.1
numpy==1.19.0
opencv-python==4.3.0.36
pefile==2019.4.18
piexif==1.1.3
Pillow==7.2.0
pyexiv2==2.3.1
Pygments==2.6.1
PyInstaller==3.6
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-magic==0.4.18
pytz==2020.1
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
requests==2.24.0
scikit-learn==0.23.1
scipy==1.5.1
self==0.0.0
six==1.15.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.18
sqlparse==0.3.1
threadpoolctl==2.1.0
train==0.0.5
urllib3==1.25.9
Werkzeug==1.0.1
WTForms==2.3.3
```

Error from console

```
C:\Flask>git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 17065, done.
Counting objects: 100% (17065/17065), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (13088/13088), done.
Writing objects: 100% (17065/17065), 251.56 MiB | 140.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 17065 (delta 3593), reused 17065 (delta 3593)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.12
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting altgraph==0.17
remote:          Downloading altgraph-0.17-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
remote:        Collecting asgiref==3.2.10
remote:          Downloading asgiref-3.2.10-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
remote:        Collecting blinker==1.4
remote:          Downloading blinker-1.4.tar.gz (111 kB)
remote:        Collecting blurhash==1.1.4
remote:          Downloading blurhash-1.1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.3 kB)
remote:        Collecting boost==0.1
remote:          Downloading boost-0.1.tar.gz (6.3 kB)
remote:        Collecting certifi==2020.6.20
remote:          Downloading certifi-2020.6.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156 kB)
remote:        Collecting chardet==3.0.4
remote:          Downloading chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
remote:        Collecting click==7.1.2
remote:          Downloading click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
remote:        Collecting cmake==3.17.3
remote:          Downloading cmake-3.17.3-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (17.6 MB)
remote:        Collecting cycler==0.10.0
remote:          Downloading cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.5 kB)
remote:        Collecting decorator==4.4.2
remote:          Downloading decorator-4.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.2 kB)
remote:        Collecting dlib==19.20.0
remote:          Downloading dlib-19.20.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
remote:        Collecting dnspython==2.0.0
remote:          Downloading dnspython-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (208 kB)
remote:        Collecting docutils==0.16
remote:          Downloading docutils-0.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl (548 kB)
remote:        Collecting email-validator==1.1.1
remote:          Downloading email_validator-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement exiv2==0.3.1 (from -r /tmp/build_92ba74db/requirements.txt (line 16)) (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for exiv2==0.3.1 (from -r /tmp/build_92ba74db/requirements.txt (line 16))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to faces-application.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/faces-application.git
 ! [remote rejected]   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/faces-application.git'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`exiv2`](https://pypi.org/project/exiv2/) **only works on Windows** while Heroku runs Linux.

You need to replace it completely. Try [`exif`](https://pypi.org/project/exif/).